# What's the procedure for having an answer converted to a comment?

Tags: support

Sometimes, especially when reviewing posts, I see answers come in from new users which don't work as answers. Some would be helpful comments, but the user doesn't have anywhere near the 50 rep needed to comment.

What appears to be a boilerplate message sometimes gets posted. It informs the user that their answer should be posted as a comment, which they will be able to do once they reach the 50 rep. That rule's in place for a reason, so that's not my point. My concern is that I don't want to scare a new user away. I also don't want us to delete something that could be useful to the person who asked the question.

If the post is on topic, not spam or rude, and is a genuine attempt to answer, a commmunity member may ask for more details in order to help them flesh out a full answer.    However,  new users don't always respond or know what to do. SE can be daunting, even if we guide people and point them to the Help Center

If a mod has converted the answer, we're all set. However, If they haven't,  and I'd like to request that, what's the procedure for asking?

I've thought about flagging the post, but don't want to do that if it's inappropriate. It will bother the mods and earn me a rejected flag!

I've considered pinging a mod in chat, but they can't necessarily take time from their other duties to check their inbox.

In this situation, what should we do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitely can flag as not an answer. The review queues or mods can then move it to a comment.

Alternatively, pinging in chat works perfectly well. It doesn't matter if the response is not immediate, mods check their inboxes at various times during the day.

And adding a comment for the new user is also a good call.

Comment: Can review queues move answers to comment? I had several instances where I wanted to do that in review (so I couldn't flag anymore, it was already), but the only option was to delete the answer. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Mods monitor review queues so can do that, or on deletion I think the poster gets a message that it wasn't an answer